# Can I use RestSharp RestClient as a singleton

Tags: asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I have read about the advantages related to Performance when using HTTPClient as a singleton and also saw some recommendations on using a shared HTTPClient. However, I was wondering if I could use the RestClient in the same way in the while calling WebAPIs in my MVC project?